# Android PATH set up in the Mac OS

Tags: android, macos

I use Mac OS and installed the Android SDK using the following command from the terminal,

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
brew cask install android-sdk
```

Then I updated the `.bash_profile` like

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Somename/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Is the path is set up correctly and how can I test that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks correct. You need to refresh your terminal with the contents of `.bash_profile` by either opening a new terminal window, or by typing

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Note the initial `.`. You can then check your path is correct by typing

```
echo $PATH
```

If all is correct, then you should be able to run binary tools within the Android SDK without specifying the full path, e.g.

```
adb devices
```

For reference, this is my own `.bashrc` file on my Debian machine:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Development/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=$HOME/Development/Android/android-ndk-r12b
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_NDK_HOME
```